# Live syntax-highlighting parser for large files

Tags: parsing, optimization, syntax-highlighting

I'm familiar with parser generators and the basics of parsers processing a stream all at once from beginning to end.

My question is for situations like syntax-highlighting text editors.  As the user makes each single character change to a very large file, there's a lot of computation that has to be performed to re-parse and re-highlight the whole file.

Easy optimizations I can think of:

- Delay that operation until the keystrokes are idle for a few seconds
- Reparse the whole file, but the formatting can be applied to only the visible viewport text

But are there generally applicable techniques to only reprocess the "local" text without starting at the beginning of the file?

Thoughts:

- Upstream affects of changes seem less impactful than downstream changes, so depending on how many lookahead tokens the algorithm allows, maybe we could reprocess from that many tokens back to the end of the file?
- We know where the cursor is at the time of most reprocessing requests, so we could capture some snapshot of the state at that point to resume from there (if that would help).

But I assume this has been solved or that someone knows that it can't work and that parsing the entire file is always necessary for general grammars.

Thanks!

Comment: NB usually syntax highlighting can be done from tokens, you don't need to parse anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax highlighting doesn't have to be precise. In fact, sometimes precise syntax highlighting is annoying (as in when the whole screen goes gray because a syntax error was introduced somewhere towards the beginning of the file). You can usually get away with:

1. Do most of the work by just colouring token classes.
2. In order to match braces, brackets and parentheses (BBP), you only have to scan backwards as far as the earliest matching BBP for a BBP visible on the screen. You can do this in the background because it doesn't usually have any consequence until the user looks for the match.
3. Sometimes tokens are hard to recognize going backwards (block comments, regular expressions). In this case, go back some fixed distance and scan forwards. A few hundred lines shouldn't add too much overhead. Alternatively (and this will work for #2 as well), cache the lexical state at strategic points, such as lines which end with a BBP at a low nesting level.

Those are just a few suggestions. There are a lot of examples of successful highlighters in the Vim and Emacs repositories, which you can look at for practical ideas for specific languages.